# Repeat values in PAW, POST request

Tags: http, request, paw-app

I wanted to ask if it is possible to repeat elements in a POST request in PAW and how to do so?

Basically, given the POST request BODY:

```
[
  { "zip":"DYNAMIC_VALUE" }
]
```

Can I then repeat this entry multiple times? Let's say I want to repeat this entry in the array 10 times, I would get for example:

```
[
  { "zip":"1234" },
  { "zip":"2543" },
  { "zip":"6543" },
  { "zip":"7645" },
  { "zip":"2654" },
  { "zip":"7568" },
  { "zip":"5364" },
  { "zip":"1313" },
  { "zip":"5432" },
  { "zip":"5634" }
]
```

And maybe I want to send an array with 1000 or more objects with a dynamic zip.
How do I do that?

Thank you :)